# Accessibility label in a button select

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

My project has a Selector element which is a native HTML `button` element under the hood. I am trying to replicate the behaviour of clicking a label and triggering an event on an input/select.

Using `<label htmlFor="size">` produces a warning during testing in Jest.

> Found a label with the text of: Size, however the element associated with this label () is non-labellable [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label]. If you really need to label a , you can use aria-label or aria-labelledby instead.

`aria-labelledby` + `id` combination will require 2 `onClick` I believe, right? Is there a more native way of doing it? What is the best practice to have a label for such element?

Comment: please post a [repro] for more details. If you do a modern and lean programming then you should split JS and HTML. This means that you don't use an `onclick` attribute in HTML but an `eventListener` in JS.

Comment: I agree, some more details are necessary. What element are you referring to with the id? You mention input/select, but both are labellable. And why are you referring to onlick, with labels correctly used, the browser will handle that for you and produce a click on the target.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your original code is correct.  You have `htmlFor` as the attribute name in your code example.  In javascript, if you want to query the value of the `for` attribute of a `<label>`, you query the `htmlFor` attribute.  But in the HTML itself, you specify the `for` attribute.

A `<button>` element **is** a [labeleable element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) so it's perfectly fine (*) to have:

```
<label for="foo">my label</label>
<button id="foo">button label</button>
```

When you click on the "my label" text, the focus goes to the button and fires the onclick event.

(*) It's perfectly fine from an HTML spec perspective.  It's **not** perfectly fine for accessibility, or at least in my example it's not ok.  The `<label>` will override the button's text when the button is announced so you'll hear "my label, button" instead of "button label, button".  This would violate [WCAG 2.5.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#label-in-name).  However, the concept of having a `<label>` for a `<button>` is valid as long as you implement it correctly to not create accessibility issues.

Comment: Exactly, it is not great considering accessibility so ideally buttons should be labeled with `aria-labelledby`, not a native `label`.

Answer (score -2):

When working with input field and labels the usual practice is:

```
<label for="my-input">
    <span>Label text:</span>
    <input id="my-input" type="SELECT|RADIO|SUBMIT|..." />
</label>
```

Now you have a similar selector **my-input** which indicates the relation between:

- **label for**
- **input id**

Then if you click the label it will trigger an event and will focus the input element.

Comment: As I said `label` produces a warning when combined with `button`. My question relates to a solution with that combination. I am aware `for` works like that natively.

Comment: Sorry but this isn’t best practice either. You should do either of wrapping the input in the label, OR referencing it with the `for` attribute. Doing both is redundant, adds unnecessary code and possibilities for errors.

Comment: It used to be that not all browsers supported nested/wrapped label elements so you also had to specify `for`.  That's not true anymore but is probably where this suggestion came from.

Comment: I am doing one not both - `for` or `aria-labelledby`. `for` is `label`'s attribute but `label` should not be used with a `button` (only with input or select).